# video stop when visibilitychange with jmuxer

Tags: javascript, video, vuejs3

i'm using jmuxer to play camera video in real time and we are in the process of drawing a video frame on a canvas.
however, when return after minimizing Chrome, the function for jmuxer feed works, but the video does not play.

this is parser code

```
const messageParser = (event) => {
  console.log("message parser");
  const origin = event.data;
  const headerValue = new Uint8Array(origin.slice(0, 2));
  const jsonSize = new DataView(origin.slice(14, 18)).getInt32() + 18;
  let lastByte = jsonSize;

  if (headerValue[1] === 126) {
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(
      new TextDecoder().decode(origin.slice(18, jsonSize))
    );

    jsonData.Image.forEach((item) => {
      streamInfo.fps = item.Draw.FPS;
      streamInfo.signalData[streamInfo.frame] = item.Draw
        ? item.Draw.Light
        : "";
      streamInfo.metaData[streamInfo.frame++] =
        item.Draw && item.Draw.Object ? item.Draw.Object : new Array();

      switch (item.Format) {
        case "h264": {
          processH264Format(item, origin, lastByte);

          break;
        }

        case "jpeg": {
          // const jpegData = origin.slice(lastByte, (lastByte += item.FrameLength));
          // this.drawFrameHandler(ch, )
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

we also checked the following to see if the video was paused

```
 document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    const isVisible = document.visibilityState === "visible";
    if (isVisible) {
      console.log(screenPlayer.value.paused);
      drawInterval.value = window.setInterval(() => {
        drawFrame();
      }, streamInfo.duration);
    } else {
      clearInterval(drawInterval.value);
    }
    booleanOptions.isFocus = isVisible;
  });
```

the parser is still running and passing the feed to jmuxer, but why isn't the video playing?

we confirmed that the function that parses video data still works, and also checked the video pause status according to visibility.